# Django ORM Model saving

Tags: django, orm

when I'm trying to interact with `SQlite` model I created, I can't save the models using:

```
<object of model>.save
```

It is prompting that:

```
<function Model.save at (some hex address)>
```

Where in tutorial there is no such error.

Can any one help me fix this?

Comment: hey you apply migration

Comment: Did you call your `save ` method with parentheses? `object.save()`

Comment: yes i did sir .